# What's this "climbing" plant with small yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

The plant has a small yellow flower. The flowers look similar (seems there is no male/female). I was thinking it is cucumber but it seems it's not!

The weather where this plant is growing is very hot and very dry!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does look a lot like a cucumber. Have you got a picture of the leaves?

Comment: I added another image where a full leave is visible. If it is cucumber why can't I find female flowers?

Comment: I think this is a honeydew/cantaloupe melon plant :)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Ah yes, I think you are right. :)

Comment: Cucumbers or melons, they're both in the same family, and some can look similar. Either way, these (squash family) plants blossom with both male flowers and female flowers on the same vine. But the distribution isn't always 50-50. Perhaps it's just lacking female flowers right now. Pretty sure that can happen, but I don't know what would cause it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like cucumber to me. Look for flowers that have a small cucumber shaped stalk. Those are the female followers which apparently come quite later than the male flowers. If you have female flowers yet no fruit, consider hand pollinating.